# Highest pressure you can go with racing type MTB tubeless tires?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire

I ride 29 inch MTBs with 2.25 front, 2.0 rear.

I usually ride on paved road (randonneuring) and occasionally slightly unpaved road (under construction).

In the past, I ran 30psi and currently I use 40psi and it runs much faster!

How high can I go with tubeless tires?
Although my tires says it can go up to 65psi (https://conti-tyres.co.uk/mtb/race-king-2-0)
(I use continental race king 2.0 inch on rear, maxis ardent race 2.25 inch on front)

I think the max is for when I use tubes.
When I run tubeless, how high can I go?
Something like 80% of max specified psi?

- Edit

I run this setup for train purposes. More resistance for training.
(But I want to know how fast I can go with this high rolling resistance setup)

I plan to use similar setup for more unpaved road in the future some thing like tour divide.

Comment: Foldable or steel-bead?

Comment: @leftaroundabout i'm not sure there is such a thing as a tubeless tyre with a rigid bead?  It's probably not technically impossible, i'm just not aware that anyone makes any

Comment: @AndyP No official ones, but people do successfully run wire bead tires as tubeless.

Comment: If the tire is tubeless, its rated for the pressure on the side wall when running tubeless. For non-tubeless,   you already outside manufacturer recommendations, but the sidewall pressure will be fine as a tube contributes nothing to pressure containment.

Comment: If you ride only paved and slightly unpaved, you should consider a gravel bike with tubes. You're using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Tubes hold the air, the tire holds the pressure.  The rated pressure on tires, especially those  labeled Tubeless will be how high you can go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question as asked:
It probably depends on your rims, [for example](https://www.lightbicycle.com/newsletter/Tubeless-Tire-Pressure-Charts.html) Light Bicycle recommends a maximum pressure of 40psi for their MTB rims.

To give a more complete answer:
What you are trying to achieve doesn't really give the results you are looking for.  Even on a perfect surface increasing to the maximum pressure does not save that much power.  Here is some rolling resistance data for a race king: [Bicycle Rolling Resistance - Race King Protection](https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/mtb-reviews/continental-race-king-protection-2020)

When you start to consider non perfect surfaces you find that differences become smaller.  The higher pressure 'feels' faster, but can in fact be slower. Personally I can't think of any reason I'd ever want to run a race king above ~35psi.  When I take my 29er on road rides I typically run around 28psi rear and 26 front for a *pure* road ride - if I'm taking even small diversions onto gravel I'll run lower than that.